# Forgotten password ext. hdd

Tags: mount, hard-drive, password

I found an old hard drive on which I once had some version of linux installed. Don't remember which. When I mount it I can mount a 255MB Filesystem folder but the rest of the drive is encrypted. I have no recollection of my password. Can anyone help me if there is a way to work around it? I am using OSX Mavericks as primary and Ubuntu as secondary OS. Any help would be appreciated.

love from DK

Answer (score 0):

If it's the default ecryptfs filesystem there is no way to crack it without the key/password. Maybe if you were NSA, but probably not. :-/

Comment: I wish. Is there any way to tell which version was installed or which kind of encryption it is?

Comment: I'm no expert in this matter so I am on thin ice here. Maybe there are some clues in the partition you are able to mount? Any interesting files, like *.mnt, *.sig, *passphrase or something like that?

If not it might be a TrueCrypt or encrypted LVM partition. What's the layout of what you can see? Try the tree command for example.

Comment: As for OS version, if there's a boot/grub/grub.cfg you should be able to find some names in the menu entries in there.